# Add 3 conditions to an actionParam from JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, flow, json-formatting

I have managed, somehow to add 2 conditions for an "actionParam" in JSON.

Now I would like to add an extra condition.

Please can anyone help me?

Thank you!

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "=if ([$Status]=='Ready for approval','{\"id\": \"958b409c-c6ff-49e6-92cc-a53f102121e5\"}',
    (if([$Status]=='Ready for re-approval','{\"id\": \"e97581e1-6ef8-4b3d-8e4b-26ec24744a03\"}',
    (if([$Status]=='Email sent'||[$Status]=='Approved','{\"id\": \"30229493-52fa-40e7-a9ca-75beb6a55229\"}','{\"id\": \"4ff20593-b570-43a7-8cca-5fb0d6c0fb7a\"}'))))"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "light",
    "background-color": "#59C3C3",
    "color": "=if([$Status]=='Ready for approval','#000000', '#FF0000')",
    "border-width": "1px",
    "border-style": "solid",
    "font-size": "14px",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "visibility": "=if(([$Status]=='Ready for approval'||[$Status]=='Ready for re-approval'||[$Status]=='Email sent'||[$Status]=='Approved' && [$ApprovalStarted]!=1),'visible','hidden')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if([$Status]=='Ready for approval'||[$Status]=='Ready for re-approval','Flow','')"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "4px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=if([$Status]=='Ready for approval','Request approval',if([$Status]=='Ready for re-approval','Request re-approval',||[$Status]=='Email sent'||[$Status]=='Approved','Copy to server '))"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below expression for `actionParams` property:

```
=if([$Status]=='Ready for approval','{\"id\": \"958b409c-c6ff-49e6-92cc-a53f102121e5\"}',if([$Status]=='Ready for re-approval','{\"id\": \"e97581e1-6ef8-4b3d-8e4b-26ec24744a03\"}',if([$Status]=='Email sent'||[$Status]=='Approved','{\"id\": \"30229493-52fa-40e7-a9ca-75beb6a55229\"}','{\"id\": \"4ff20593-b570-43a7-8cca-5fb0d6c0fb7a\"}')))
```

Where `[$Status]` is the internal name of your status column.
You can get the exact internal name of your SharePoint list column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

---

Your full JSON code with my above condition added:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "=if([$Status]=='Ready for approval','{\"id\": \"958b409c-c6ff-49e6-92cc-a53f102121e5\"}',if([$Status]=='Ready for re-approval','{\"id\": \"e97581e1-6ef8-4b3d-8e4b-26ec24744a03\"}',if([$Status]=='Email sent'||[$Status]=='Approved','{\"id\": \"30229493-52fa-40e7-a9ca-75beb6a55229\"}','{\"id\": \"4ff20593-b570-43a7-8cca-5fb0d6c0fb7a\"}')))"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "light",
    "background-color": "#59C3C3",
    "color": "=if([$Status]=='Ready for approval','#000000', '#FF0000')",
    "border-width": "1px",
    "border-style": "solid",
    "font-size": "14px",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "visibility": "=if(([$Status]=='Ready for approval'||[$Status]=='Ready for re-approval'||[$Status]=='Email sent'||[$Status]=='Approved' && [$ApprovalStarted]!=1),'visible','hidden')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if([$Status]=='Ready for approval'||[$Status]=='Ready for re-approval','Flow','')"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "4px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=if([$Status]=='Ready for approval','Request approval',if([$Status]=='Ready for re-approval','Request re-approval',||[$Status]=='Email sent'||[$Status]=='Approved','Copy to server '))"
    }
  ]
}
```